# How to use a single count for tables and figures?

Tags: tables, floats, numbering

In a short document, I wrote reference-based sentence, which ended up reading :

> With the previous example (figure 1), the features used are presented in table 1.

I would like both figures and tables to share the same counter, so after figure 1 comes table 2, then table 3, figure 4, etc.

**How can I merge the counts for tables and figures ?**

A similar question was asked on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865036/using-a-single-count-for-figures-and-tables-in-latex)) but I couldn't make the answers work.

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3866061?

Comment: `\makeatletter\let\c@table\c@figure\makeatother` on preamble.

Comment: @Sigur I did, but not thoroughly enough. It works now, thanks.